# Comparing time in iOS to allow user to post again

Tags: ios, objective-c, datetime, time

I'm working on a sample app which posts a string to server. I want to allow the user to post only two minutes after his previous post. I could do this on the server side but it might take long to get a response from the server when the user has a slow internet connection. So, I'm planning to do it on the client side(iPhone). I just want to compare the time between the current and previous post. Can anyone help me with saving time of the previous post. Sorry if anyone finds the question stupid.

Comment: you can use NSUserDefaults to save previous time .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This needs to be re-thought from architecture point of view.

If a user posts then you can count the time... but if as a user will TRY to post, the response fails, then again you need to reset the time. So this is same as you are worried about the response from the server may take long.

Assuming everything goes well then:

As you need to know when is the post successfully posted. Then you need to get the response and save the time somewhere, can me userdefaults or plist.

Comment: Thanks a lot I will work on what u said, it makes a lot more sense...;)

Answer (score 1):

This should help :-

```
NSUserDefaults* defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

NSTimeInterval currentTime = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
NSString* timeStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", currentTime];

float recentPostTime = [[defaults objectForKey:@"Recent_Post_Time"] floatValue];

if(currentTime-recentPostTime > 120.0f)
{
    //Post to server here..

    //Update Recent Post Time in user defaults
    [defaults setObject:timeStr forKey:@"Recent_Post_Time"];
    [defaults synchronize];
}
else
{
    //Alert the user that he/she can't post within 2 minutes again
}
```

Comment: NSUserDefaults can store NSDate objects, so there is no need to convert the date to a string.